# How to return values with serial, nested conditions of a list?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, list, numpy

I'm trying to implement an algorithm in a boolean list. It looks like:

```
price_list = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
```

Let's say it captures daily price change of a stock, such as `0` means a decrease and `1` means an increase of price.

Consider a block of 4 days. Starting on the first day, if the price drops (value `0`), return `-1` and bid `1` on the second day. If the price increases (value `1`), return `1` and bid `2` on the second day.

In the second day, if the price drops, return `-2` and bid `1` on the third day. If it increases, return `2` and bid `3` on the third day.

On the third day, if the price drops, return `-3` and bid `1` on the fourth day. If it increases, return `3` and bid `4` on the fourth day.

On the fourth day, if the price drops, return `-4`. If it increases, return `4`. Either way, bid `1` on the next day. We can say then that it finishes a circle of bidding. The issue here is it can only be finished, or converged, if there are 3 days of price increase, so that regardless of the result in day 4, we go back to bidding `1`. Otherwise, the bidding of the next day will depend on the previous day(s).

Applying this rule for the above list, the return list will be:

```
price_list =  [ 0, 1, 1,  0, 1,  0, 1, 1, 1, 1,  0,  0,  0, 1, 1,  0,  0, 1]

return_list = [-1, 1, 3, -2, 1, -3, 1, 3, 2, 4, -1, -1, -1, 1, 3, -2, -1, 1]
```

EDIT: Got a few comments asking for my code, perhaps to show some attempt. It's still unfinished though (in fact I think I'm going nowhere with this)

```
df_temp = pd.DataFrame({'price' : np.random.randint(0, 2, 1000) })
df_temp['block'] = df_temp['price'].groupby(df_temp['price'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()).transform('count')
df_temp['block_shift'] = df_temp['block'].shift(1)
df_temp['mask'] = df_temp['block'] == df_temp['block_shift']
df_temp['cs'] = df_temp['mask'].cumsum() - df_temp['mask'].cumsum().where(~df_temp['mask']).ffill().fillna(0) + 1
df_temp['block_2'] = df_temp['block']
df_temp.loc[(df_temp['block'] > 4) & (df_temp['cs'] <= 4) , 'block_2'] = 4
df_temp.loc[(df_temp['cs'] > 4) & (df_temp['cs'] % 4 != 0) , 'block_2'] = df_temp['cs'] % 4
df_temp.loc[(df_temp['cs'] > 4) & (df_temp['cs'] % 4 == 0) , 'block_2'] = 4
```

Comment: Try to post your sample code here.

Comment: And the part where you try to implement the algorithm?

Comment: @HenryYik My attempt is a bunch of if conditions, but it doesn't work and I get stuck in the middle of the way so I don't post it. Is it required?